# How to invoke the getter in the POJO through reflection API

Tags: java, reflection

There is one getter method say `getAddressText1()` i want to invoke on a pojo which is designed in the following way -:

```
public class AccountDetails{

public String name;
public Address address;
.
.
//getters and setters
}
```

now This `addressText1` inside the `Address`

something like

```
public class Address{

public String addressText1;
.
.
//getters and setters
}
```

now if i will invoke the getAddressText1 on the AccountDetails its going to throw the methodnotfound exception.

Since this is the Reflection I dont have a control to apply on Address directly.

Please reply if you know the solution.

Thanks!!

Comment: so first get the Address, then get the addressText. your variables probably should be declared private

Comment: @Stultuske this whole thing is generic i will be getting the method name from the property file. lets us suppose -:
firstly i will be getting the getName() then through i have to apply it through invoke function as getName().invoke(accountObject).
then i will be getting the getAddressText1() then i will be invoking it on the accountObject as getAddressText1().invoke(accountObject )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `addressText1` from `address` create a method inside `AccountDetails` eg `getAddress` (if you don't have that already):

```
public class AccountDetails {

    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    // Other code
}
```

Then you can call:

```
String addressText1 = myAccountVariable.getAddress().getAddressText1();
```

Where `myAccountVariable` is an `AccountDetails` object.

Comment: I am doing it through Reflection API.everything has to be done during run time.

Comment: @RishabhBansal that is nonsense. calling a getter is runtime. using reflection for this is trying to get rid of that pesky mosquito with a nuclear warhead

Comment: @Stultuske Please try to understand the question first.
you are getting the method from somewhere else like getName(),getAddressText1(). We just have to map with the Master POJO which is AccountDetail in our case.
And since we dont have the explicit mapping of address1 the exception will be method not found.

Comment: so, you want from your AccountDetails to "magically" get addressText1 ? even weirder, you want based on the getName() call to get addressText1 ? What if later on a second Address is added?

Comment: Do you believe that coding gives you data magically ..?
First read the requirement carefully then make these kind of comments..
I think you should groom your knowledge towards Reflection API first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `getAddressText1()` inside your `AccountDetails` you simply create the getter method of `Address` object  which you have defined in your AccountDetails class.

After using the `getAddress()` method you can call the method defined in Address class as;

```
String address = accountDetailsObj.getAddress().getAddressText1();
```

accountDetailsObj is the object of `AccountDetails` class.

Comment: he doesn't have to create a getter, according his description, there is one